# Apache in Front, Tomcat in Back, but SSL isn't working?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat

I have Apache setup as my web server, and Tomcat is hooked into Apache via `mod_jk`, so the user never interacts with Tomcat.

I have set up SSL on Apache, and I can hit it with `https://localhost`, but when I try to access my application at `https://localhost/app`, I get a `directory not found` error.

The catch is when I go regular http, I can hit it fine: `http://localhost/app`

What do I have to edit for this connection to work?

- I have uncommented the AJP connector in `server.xml`
- I have added my virtual host to `httpd.conf`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The http and https are considered different virtual servers by Apache. Did you set up your reverse proxy under both virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0):

you need to replicate the setup you have from http to https
- you don't need the ajp connector if you have a http connector

look how it is setup - probably it does a proxy pass or uses
a RewriteRule with the P at the end which is a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition for workers could be wrong. Check workers.properties for work's type. If ajp13, unconmment your ajp section in tomcat back as it was.
mod_jk usually uses ajp13 as type.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if configured correctly. Just another thing to check - that your proxy pass rules are accessible within the SSL connection. It is possible to configure the SSL version of a website to be different from the non-SSL version. Make sure that your proxy pass configuration is sitting in both.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mod_jk, you need the AJP connector in Tomcat.

In most cases, if the worker has a configuration problem, Apache will answer with a 500
error (Server error).  If you get a 404, this is rather because the request does not get passed to the Tomcat server (or the URL is invalid from Tomcat point of view).  Check
that the JkMount is present and correct in your Apache configuration (for the 443 port).

To debug problems with mod_jk, turn on the debug logs in mod_jk and look at Apache logs.
Add these lines in mod_jk configuration (jk.conf in general):

JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log

JkLogLevel debug

You should see some logs at startup and some interesting details for each request.

I did this kind of setup for Apache2 + SSL + JBoss.  You will find other details
and optimisation tips in
[Deploying a J2EE application behind an Apache server in a production environment](http://blog.vacs.fr/index.php?post/2008/04/13/12-deploying-a-j2ee-application-behind-an-apache-server-in-a-production-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article.  It explains exactly how to do mod_jk with https.  It is accomplished via a secure virtual host which then communicates to Tomcat on the same standard AJP channel you use with non secure connection.

http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/howto_blogs/1464-2_ways_to_setup_ssl_on_tomcat_7